# weblogic wlst console does not show full list of environment variables

Tags: python, ubuntu, environment-variables, weblogic, jython

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

When running the `wlst.sh` within my weblogic server, I am trying to get the value of a env var but the value is not there. However when checking the dict `os.env` it only contains two env vars (it is missing most of them, e.g JAVA_HOME).
This is what the sequence of actions I am doing:

```
$export MY_VAR=123
$$MW_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option 
MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

wls:/offline> print str(os.environ)
{'FZF_DEFAULT_OPTIONS': '--extended\n\t--color 
fg:240,bg:230,hl:33,fg+:241,bg+:221,hl+:33\n\t--color 
info:33,prompt:33,pointer:166,marker:166,spinner:33', 
'VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD': '1'}
```

My exported var and many others are no there.

Running the same in a fresh new intallation retrieves the full set of env vars.

If I run it within my python (2.7) console it does retrieve the full set too.

Comment: I have finally track this issue down. In my .bashrc I have a environment var define over two lines:

Answer (score 0):

I have finally track this issue down. In my .bashrc I have a environment var define over two lines:

```
export MY_VAR="bla_bla
"
```

That cause the jython interpreter(version 2.2.1) within weblogic to load only the environment vars until it found that one, that's why the dic `os.environ` was partially loaded.

Thats, however, handle fine and all env vars were loaded within my python terminal either 2.7 or 3.5